Sidebar under stuff on small screens
Am making a archive.org like website but the sidebar is a sidebar on desktop but going to localhost on my phone is under everything else am using node.js and EJS the header is just a title and mainifest. It sussposed to be you click on actions to unhide/show the sidebar but it places it under the other stuff
torrent.ejs
<head>
  <%- include('partials/head') %>
  <script type="module" src="https://md-block.verou.me/md-block.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/md2ab.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/vote.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="text-gray-100">
  <%- include('partials/navbar', { session: session }) %>

  <!-- Sidebar toggle button for mobile -->
  <button id="sidebar-toggle" class="lg:hidden bg-purple-600 text-white p-3 rounded fixed bottom-4 right-4 z-50 transition transform hover:scale-105">
    Actions
  </button>

  <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen lg:flex-row">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside id="sidebar" class="w-full bg-gray-800 p-6 lg:w-64 lg:block lg:relative lg:h-auto fixed bottom-0 lg:bottom-auto lg:left-0 lg:top-0 transform -translate-x-full lg:translate-x-0 opacity-0 lg:opacity-100 transition-transform transition-opacity duration-500 ease-out">
      <h2 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4 text-purple-300">Actions</h2>

      <div class="mt-2 mb-4">
        <p class="text-gray-400">Rating: <span class="text-purple-400"><%= torrent.votes || 0 %></span></p>
        <p class="text-gray-400">Views: <span class="text-purple-400"><%= torrent.views || 0 %></span></p>
      </div>

      <% if (torrent.magnet) { %>
      <div class="space-y-4">
        <a href="/uploads/<%= torrent.torrent %>" download class="block text-purple-500 hover:underline">Download Torrent</a>
        <a href="<%= torrent.magnet %>" target="_blank" class="block text-purple-500 hover:underline">Open Magnet</a>
        <% if (torrent.directDownload) { %>
        <a href="<%= torrent.directDownload %>" target="_blank" class="block text-purple-500 hover:underline transition transform hover:scale-105" onclick="window.open('<%= torrent.directDownload %>', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600'); return false;">Direct download</a>
        <% } %>
        <% if (torrent.sourceURL) { %>
        <a href="<%= torrent.sourceURL %>" target="_blank" class="block text-purple-500 hover:underline transition transform hover:scale-105">Source</a>
        <% } %>
        <% if (torrent.normalSource) { %>
        <a href="<%= torrent.normalSource %>" target="_blank" class="block text-purple-500 hover:underline transition transform hover:scale-105">Normal Source</a>
        <% } %>
        <% if (torrent.streamURL) { %>
        <a href="<%= torrent.streamURL %>" target="_blank" class="block text-purple-500 hover:underline transition transform hover:scale-105" onclick="window.open('<%= torrent.streamURL %>', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600'); return false;">Stream</a>
        <% } %>
        <button onclick="downloadTorrentAsJSON()" class="block text-purple-500 hover:underline transition transform hover:scale-105">Download as JSON</button>
      </div>
      <% } %>

      <div class="mt-6">
        <% if (session.userId) { %>
        <% if (torrent.userVotes && torrent.userVotes[session.userId]) { %>
        <p class="text-gray-400">You have already <%= torrent.userVotes[session.userId] %>d on this torrent.</p>
        <% } else { %>
        <form action="/torrent/<%= torrent.id %>/vote" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="vote" id="voteType" value="">
          <div class="flex space-x-2">
            <button type="button" onclick="submitVote('upvote')" class="text-green-500 hover:underline transition transform hover:scale-105">Upvote</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="submitVote('downvote')" class="text-red-500 hover:underline transition transform hover:scale-105">Downvote</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>
      </div>

      <% if (session.userId && session.userId !== torrent.uploadedBy) { %>
      <div class="flex justify-center mt-6">
        <form action="/torrent/<%= torrent.id %>/report" method="post">
          <button type="submit" class="bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded w-full transition transform hover:scale-105">
            Report
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <% } %>

      <% if (session.userId && session.userId === torrent.uploadedBy) { %>
      <div class="flex justify-center mt-6">
        <a href="/torrent/<%= torrent.id %>/edit" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded transition transform hover:scale-105">
          Edit
        </a>
      </div>
      <% } %>
    </aside>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main class="flex-1 bg-gray-900 p-6">
      <div class="main-content flex flex-col lg:flex-row gap-8 opacity-0 transform scale-95 transition-opacity transition-transform duration-600 ease-out">
        <div class="torrent-details bg-gray-800 p-6 rounded-lg shadow-lg max-w-2xl w-full">
          <header class="mb-6">
            <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold text-purple-400"><%= torrent.name %></h1>
          </header>
          <div class="space-y-4">
            <% if (torrent.icon) { %>
            <img src="/uploads/<%= torrent.icon %>" alt="<%= torrent.name %>" class="w-full h-auto mb-4 rounded-lg">
            <% } %>
            <% if (torrent.seedsersAtTime) { %>
            <p class="text-gray-300"><strong>Seeders At Time: <%= torrent.seedsersAtTime %></strong></p>
            <% } %>
            <p class="text-gray-300"><strong>Description:</strong>
              <md-block> <%= torrent.description %></md-block>
            </p>
            <p class="text-gray-300">
              <strong>Added By:</strong>
              <a href="/profile/<%= torrent.uploadedBy %>" class="text-purple-500 hover:underline">
                <%= torrent.username || 'Unknown' %>
              </a>
            </p>
            <p class="text-gray-300"><strong>Added On:</strong> <%= new Date(torrent.uploadedAt).toLocaleDateString() %></p>
            <!-- Tags section -->
            <% if (torrent.tags && torrent.tags.length > 0) { %>
            <p class="text-gray-300"><strong>Tags:</strong>
              <span class="flex flex-wrap space-x-2 mt-2">
                <% torrent.tags.forEach(tag => { %>
                <a href="/tags/<%= tag %>" class="bg-purple-500 text-white py-1 px-3 rounded-full mb-2 hover:bg-purple-400 transition"><%= tag %></a>
                <% }) %>
              </span>
            </p>
            <% } %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="comments-section flex-1 bg-gray-900 p-6">
          <section>
            <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold text-purple-400 mb-4">Comments</h2>
            <div class="comments-list mt-4 space-y-4 bg-gray-800 p-6 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
              <% if (comments.length > 0) { %>
              <% comments.forEach(comment => { %>
              <div class="comment-item bg-gray-700 p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md">
                <p class="comment-text text-gray-300 break-words whitespace-pre-wrap">
                  <strong class="text-purple-400"><%= comment.username %>:</strong> <%= comment.text %>
                </p>
              </div>
              <% }) %>
              <% } else { %>
              <p class="text-gray-400">No comments yet.</p>
              <% } %>
            </div>

            <% if (session.userId) { %>
            <form action="/torrent/<%= torrent.id %>/comment" method="post" class="comment-form mt-6">
              <textarea name="comment" rows="3" class="w-full p-3 bg-gray-700 text-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-500" placeholder="Add your comment..."></textarea>
              <button type="submit" class="bg-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-700 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-lg mt-2 transition transform hover:scale-105">
                Post Comment
              </button>
            </form>
            <% } %>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>

  <script>
    function downloadTorrentAsJSON() {
      const torrentData = <%- JSON.stringify(torrent) %>;
      const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(torrentData, null, 2)], {
        type: 'application/json'
      });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = '<%= torrent.name %>.json';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }

    // Trigger the loaded state for animations
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      document.body.classList.add("loaded");
      const aside = document.querySelector("aside");
      if (aside) {
        aside.classList.remove("transform", "-translate-x-full", "opacity-0");
      }
      const mainContent = document.querySelector(".main-content");
      if (mainContent) {
        mainContent.classList.remove("opacity-0", "scale-95");
      }
    });

    // Sidebar toggle for mobile
    const sidebarToggle = document.getElementById('sidebar-toggle');
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    sidebarToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
      sidebar.classList.toggle('-translate-x-full');
      sidebar.classList.toggle('opacity-100');
    });
  </script>
</body>

I have tried moveing the sidebar and asking a AI what's worng with it but nothing seems to work.

I can't answer your question, but have a look at the z-index CSS property, It can help you to put one thing in front of another. You can find the current z-index with the browser's developer tools.

It's difficult to answer your question without the CSS of your classes. But as @KIKOSoftware mentions, checkout z-index and maybe also the isolation css property.
